# Limit the number of rows returned based on the user's role

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I would like to have a control on db users to select the tables in sql. For ex. There is a user named 'user1' and another one is 'user2'.

User1 has admin Role on the database. User2 has a lower role. When a user runs a query, i want to check the username and userrole, if its an admin user, then i allow it to run. If its a lower role user, i need to limit the result of the query (not deny, just limit.) for ex. I dont want the lower role user to see the PhoneNumber column on the table so i need to give that user the result as the table except the PhoneNumber column.

I know i can do this on column permissions in roles area. But i also want to limit the query like: just return top (5) result, not all the table.

So i need a stored procedure or something like that, that automatically runs when a user execute the query. Is there any kind of sp or something else like that in sql ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, there is not. And what do you mean by `f5`, you give your users access to SSMS? Your best approach would be to remove access using roles to restricted tables and allow results by executing against stored procedures. In the stored proc you can check roles/rights and return what is appropriate. Alternatively you can use Sql Views and grant/limit rights to those views. The whole write-up sounds kinda hack-y to me though, probably better you re-evaluate the actual requirements then try to push this through especially if users already have rights to use SSMS.

Comment: If the application is not SSMS, what is it?

Comment: they use ssms to connect to sql instance. this is not my question though. All i need is a control between 'user runs the query' and 'sql returns the result'. i need to check the query that the user wants to run. then i decide what to give to sql server to give the results that i want.

Comment: for ex. lower role user runs a query like 'SELECT * FROM Customer'. Customer table has 1 billion rows. I dont want that user to see all the rows. I just want to give that user the top(5) result. so i need a control like: if query like '%SELECT%*%' SET query = 'SELECT TOP(5) ...' then run the query.

Comment: That is not how permissions work. If you want to limit the results then create different views for the different roles and grant each role rights to their own respective view. You can even bind the view to a named schema so you can reuse the name and set that schema as the default schema for each role. But generally if you have read access to table object and its columns then you cant limit which records the user can read.

Comment: oh, isnt there any trigger like AFTER EXECUTE or something ?

Comment: Users are working through SSMS?? Weird! Use some another *provider*, Access with simple forms that got data from stored procedures (like was mentioned before) or wrote some other (on PHP, ASP.NET etc). Such limitation are not built in SSMS. If there are some basic selects - use SSRS to provide some reports.

Comment: You may be able to use dynamic data masking in sql server 2016 to obfuscate the column data for the specific user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do that directly.

You can do some things with a table-valued function, such as appending a WHERE clause based on the user's role. But there's no way to do that with the TOP operator, as that has to be applied last.

In theory you could introduce SQL rewriting with your own variant of sp_execute, but in practice that would introduce huge holes for SQL injection attacks.

Options:

1. Handle the restriction at the application level.
2. Revoke SELECT permissions on the table and expose it via stored procedures only. You'll potentially need a lot of stored procedures to account for all of the various ways the users may want the data.

Comment: I wish I wasn't. That sounds like a useful ability to have.